# Swift - Selecting item in Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I'm having a problem with selected items in a collection view.

Selected items change backgroundColor to blue, but it seems like the reusable cells are also affected.

my code looks like this:

```html
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell?
  cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeslectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell?
  cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UIControllerView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell: boxCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("demoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as boxCell

  cell.cellTitle.text = name[indexPath.row]
}
```

When I run the application, the selection works, selecting another cell, deselects the other selected cells, but when I scroll, the reusable cells are also turning blue.

I am using a horizontal scroll direction with only 1 row and 4 cells per row.

Where did I go wrong? Anybody else have had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behavior - the reason for that is that the items are reused, and after reusing they go through `cellForItemAtIndexPath` where you are not setting background color, so they keep last one you ever set - in your case didSelect method.

You should create a `NSSet` where you will keep all selected `NSIndexPath`'s and add / remove `NSIndexPath` to it when selecting / deselecting.

Setting background color logic should be done in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` - after you check if `NSIndexPath` is existing in your `NSSet` you set a desired color.

On selection you will have to also reload certain element, so it will call `cellForItemAtIndexPath` for the one you clicked.

Comment: Just a little reminder: If you are using swift 1.2 use native Set type instead of NSSet

Answer (score 0):

Use the prepare for resue method in your cell class.It will work fine.

```
override func prepareForReuse()
 {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
 }
```